# Microsite layouts and Content Areas

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites

If a content area is updated, is it possible to auto-publish those updates to the landing pages that use it?

It would seem that in order to see those updates, one must manually update each landing page individually.

Curious if anyone has experience with this. Thank you.

Comment: I assume this is a Marketing-cloud (a.k.a. ExactTarget) [microsite](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/)? I've tagged it as such to increase the odds that the right person will see it and provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to Content Areas do not require republishing landing or microsite pages -- which is a pro and a con of creating modular content using Content Areas.

EDIT: Assuming you're using the [ContentAreaByName()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/ContentAreaByName.html) function to retrieve the Content Area.

Comment: That's interesting as that is not my experience. Retrieved a simple copy only content area within a landing page created from a layout, published, changed the original content area text, then checked the page and it wasn't updated. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you use the [ContentAreaByName()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/ContentAreaByName.html) function, you won't have to republish. Thanks for calling that out.  I've updated my answer.